# How to solve this User Input problem in countdown timer Python3.9.4

Tags: python, timer, conditional-statements, countdown

I have a countdown timer that asks for user input for a "lucky number". Once that number is entered, the timer starts to countdown and prints out a simple message.

My problem is that if the user input is not a number, I get the "Traceback (most recent call last) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10"

I understand what that means, but I don't know how to make it bypass this condition so that the user input can be **anything** (not just numbers) and not give me an error, but rather just print out a message that would just say; "continue without lucky number"..-and just continue with the rest of the script..

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of the code
[image: Here is a screenshot of the code]

Comment: Please, do not post code as an image. Any effort to turn this into a [quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "would be highly appreciated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

treat the user input as a string and then use a try-except to determine whether or not it is a number

```
try: 
  number = int(stringvar)
except:
  print("continue without lucky number")
```

you could also then generate a random number for your timer if the user did not enter a number

```
import time
import random

def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1

num = input("Enter your lucky number: ")

isNum = False

try:
    i = int(num)
    isNum = True
except:
    print("Continue without lucky number")

if isNum:
    countdown(i)
else:
    rand = random.randint(1, 100)
    countdown(rand)
    print(f"timer number is: {rand}")
```

that can be your whole timer program.

Comment: Fascinating! Works exactly how I imagined it but didn't know how to implement. Means a lot, thank you Cameron!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a certain message if it is not an integer instead of running the function then you can either use an `if... else` loop or `try... except` loop. For example:

```
try:
    countdown(int(t))
except ValueError:
    if input("Continue without lucky number?") == "y":
        countdown(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Errors should never pass silently.
> Unless explicitly silenced.

However, apart from catching the error, you can do another thing in my opinion. Say your variable name is `var`,

```
if not var.isdigit():
    var = ord(var)
```

Here, the functin `ord()` will return the ASCII value of the character which will be an integer obviously and your code will run successfully.